# Can I use value arrtibute in article tag in React Component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

When I click the article, I need to show the title of article.

So I coded like this:

```
const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
...
return(
<article value={title} onClick={e=>setTitle(e.target.value)}>
{title}
</article>
...
```

Comment: What's the goal here? Because that code looks like it just tries to set `title` to what it already is....? (I'm guessing your real code is more complex and you simplified for the question, but unfortunately may have gone a bit too far. :-) )

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

No, [`article`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-article-element) has no `value` attribute and thus no `value` property on its element type. It doesn't have any attributes at all other than the [global ones](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#global-attributes) all elements have, which don't include `value`.

You could use a [`data-*` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) instead, perhaps accessing it through [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) (or you could just use `getAttribute("data-value")`):

```
<article data-value={title} onClick={(e) => setTitle(e.currentTarget.dataset.value)}>
```

...but there's no need unless there are aspects not shown in the question; you already have `title`, which your `onClick` function closes over, so:

```
<article data-value={title} onClick={(e) => setTitle(title)}>
```

...but that reveals an issue: It seems you're trying to set the title to what it already is. (I'm guessing your real code is more complex and you've simplified it for the question.)

Comment: @Tyne - Happy to help. :-) There are definitely times the `data-*` attribute approach is useful (mostly when you want to reuse a single event handler across multiple elements instead of relying on the closure), but I didn't do a runnable example because I wasn't sure it would really be relevant. I'd be glad to, though, if it would help. Happy coding!